# how do i view an active storage uploaded image from my index file, this error comes up

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

<%= image_tag (complaint.image) %>
This line breeds this error,
Can't resolve image into URL: to_model delegated to attachment, but the attachment is nil 
 Without the image_tag, I get an active_storage object; # , how then do I get past this

Comment: did you print complaint object in view file , is that object nil? you can print that object using <%= complaint.inspect %> and check what you are getting. you can check this reference how image tag working https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/AssetTagHelper/image_tag

Comment: @NeerajAmoli if `complaint` was nil it would cause a NoMethodError.

Comment: @max user which ask question seems new to ROR , that's why i suggest for debugging first . the answer you gave is perfect if there is nil object :)

Comment: @Kihara a bit of advice so you can find SO more useful. 

Make sure you take some time to format your question appropriately. Add spaces so things are clearer and most importantly the code bits must be formatted correctly, wrapping them like:  ```your code here````.  

Also, if you give more context and show that you have made  previous attempts to solve your problem it'll help other users to guide you more efficiently. 

Welcome to SO and hope you find it useful!

Answer (score 0):

Just check if its nil before displaying the image.

```
<%= image_tag(complaint.image) if complaint.image %>
```

Also do NOT put a space between the method name and the parens in Ruby. Since parens are optional in Ruby it will be treated as a single argument and not a list of arguments.

```
foo (bar, baz) # causes a syntax error
```